# HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing проблема доступа к jsp странице

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Всем привет, разбираюсь со Spring MVC и поймал ошибку, которую не могу решить. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

При переходе на http://localhost:9909/user-system/users/validate

выдает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

контроллер:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userService.getAllUser();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView validatorUser(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("userFromServer", new User());
        modelAndView.setViewName("users_check_page");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/check", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String checkUser(@ModelAttribute("userFromServer") User user){
        if("admin".equals(user.getName()) && "admin".equals(user.getPassword())){
            return  "valid";
        }
        return  "invalid";
    }
}
```

страница users_check_page.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<spring:form modelAttribute="userFromServer" method="post" action="/user-system/users/check">
    <spring:input path="name"/>
    <spring:input path="password"/>
    <spring:button>check user</spring:button>
</spring:form>
</body>
</html>
```

spring-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="system"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="users_page"/>

    <bean id="resolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

плагин в pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
   <configuration>
       <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
       <httpConnector>
           <port>9909</port>
       </httpConnector>
       <webApp>
           <contextPath>
               /user-system
           </contextPath>
       </webApp>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измени в spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста, разве не любой id можем указывать? какой материал поискать на эту тему?

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский нет, не любой (обязательно "viewResolver", Spring Container ищет бин именно с таким id).

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский рекомендую почитать книгу Pro Spring 5